# Reduce Space Before Table and Between Table to New Section

Tags: tables, spacing, sectioning, captions, longtable

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \lipsum[4]
    \FloatBarrier
    \begingroup
    \setlength\extrarowheight{11pt}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
            \caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} \label{table1}\\
            \hline
            Variable1&Variable2&Variable3\\
            \hline
            uxbwyy&xneio22xi&nc33i3\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}
            { 
                Source: cnihe3i3nixom;
            }
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \endgroup
    \FloatBarrier
    \section{Section Two}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I want to reduce the space (red line) but, I don't want to use `\vspace*{-...mm}`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Vertical space around your table depends from content of the next page.
- Why you use `longtable`?
- With small changes of table code as

  - table is inserted in `center` environment, so it not float so the use of the `\FloatBarrier` superfluous
  - using `tabular` instead of `longtable`
  - using `captionof{figure}{...}` instead `\caption{...}`
  - employing `copyrightbox` package for notes of table source

  the result of MWE is:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin={4cm,3cm},vmargin={4cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \lipsum[4]
%    \FloatBarrier
    \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{11pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \captionof{figure}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} 
    \label{table1}
    \copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Variable1&Variable2&Variable3\\
            \hline
            uxbwyy&xneio22xi&nc33i3\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}}{Source: cnihe3i3nixom;}
     \end{center}

    \section{Section Two}
%    \FloatBarrier
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** In the case that you really need long table, than image in your question, which illustrate your problem, can't ever happened. For example, that long table is similar to use in MWE below, then it produce the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin={4cm,3cm},vmargin={4cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\begingroup
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{That is my longtable, which is supposed to reproduce my problem}
    \label{:tab:longtable}          \\
    \hline
\thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text}   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{That is my longtable, which is supposed 
               to reproduce my problem (cont.)}             \\
    \hline
\thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \multicolumn{4}{r @{}}{\small\emph{continue on the next page}}  \\*
    \multicolumn{4}{@{} l}{\small Source: cnihe3i3nixom}    \\
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
%%%% table nody    
Variable 1   & Variable 2   & Variable 3   & variable 4     \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \hline
uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

    \section{Section Two}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use longtable because actually my table has many rows.

Comment: @Lis, so many that it need to be split over many pages? Your  MWE doesn't indicate this. In case that you really need l`long table. your problem can arise only in the case that you table have  cells with many lines, which cannot be split between cell.

Comment: Yes, actually my table needs to be split over some pages. My MWE is just a simple example with one row. What must I do if my MWE has so many rows until it needs to be split over next page?

Comment: @Lis, than your question is misleading. As I already mentioned, using long table in the most of case not cause of your problem, especially showed one not.

Comment: Sorry, I just focused on my space (red line) problem.

Comment: @Wind, see addendum in answer.

Comment: Wow, my problem solved. Thank you so much.