# Decreasing gap size of equation and centering the "text" in first row of table

Tags: tables, equations, gap, center

I want make a table as @Zarko's answer in [Reduce Space Before Table and Between Table to New Section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580948/reduce-space-before-table-and-between-table-to-new-section). But I have a problem:

[image]

The "text" in first row does not center of cell. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={4cm,3cm},vmargin={4cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \begingroup
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \caption{That is my longtable, which is supposed to reproduce my problem}
        \label{:tab:longtable}          \\
        \hline
        \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text}   \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{That is my longtable, which is supposed 
            to reproduce my problem (cont.)}             \\
        \hline
        \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text} & \thead{text}   \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{4}{r @{}}{\small\emph{continue on the next page}}  \\*
        \multicolumn{4}{@{} l}{\small Source: cnihe3i3nixom}    \\
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %%%% table nody    
        Variable 1   & Variable 2   & Variable 3   & variable 4     \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
        \hline
        uxbwyy       & xneio22xi    & nc33i3       & 44444          \\
    \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
    \lipsum[6-8]
    \[\int \sin x dx = -\cos x +c\]
    where $c$ is constant.
\end{document}
```

If I omit the code:

```
\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
        \setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
        \setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
        \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
        \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
    }
\makeatother
```

the "text" in first row can centered but there is gap before and after the equation:

[image]

So, I want both of decreasing gap size of equation and centering the "text" in first row.

Anyone can help me to do that?

Comment: Replace`\ thead` with `\textbf``. This should help in table(s). Showed space above/below equation I can't reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- more space around column headers written by `\thead` is determined by design, so if you not liked it, than don't use it. Replace it by `\textbf`:

[image]

- I can't reproduce bigger vertical space around your equation, but observe discrepancy between math and text font height.
- you should be aware, that `helvet` font is about 20% higher than math font defined in `newtxmath`.
- for removing this remedy you have two possibilities:

  - used scaled `helvet` fonts:

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

- instead `helvet` fonts use `newtxtext`, which is better paired with `newtxmath`:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Use of not scaled `helvet`:

[image]

Use of scaled `helvet`:

[image]

Use of `newtxtext`:

[image: \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}]